# Where to download 4 band NAIP imagery?

Tags: imagery, remote-sensing, download

I seem to recall USGS [Earthexplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) providing current and historic 4 band [NAIP imagery](http://www.fsa.usda.gov/FSA/apfoapp?area=home&subject=prog&topic=nai) over the last few years.  It appears that these data have been migrated to the [National Map](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/).  However, the National Map only appears to have 2011 4-band NAIP imagery.  The USDA FSA points users to the NRCS [Geospatial Data Gateway](http://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/), although these downloads only appear to be 3 band images without the nIR band.

1. **What are the best sources for downloading *historic and current* 4 band NAIP imagery at 1m spatial resolution?**
2. **Are there any Oregon specific download sites?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To acquire NAIP for Oregon that includes the NIR band you must contact the OGEO office directly (gisgis.state.or.us or 503-378-2166). The NIR is not available on the download site.

When you refer to "historic" NAIP including the NIR band you are going to be somewhat out of luck. Many states still do not include NIR in their contracts and the USDA-APFO option of a NIR band was not officially added to the contract template, as part of NAIP, until 2009. To acquire this data you will have to go state by state. Colorado has an ftp site that you can download the current, quad-level, NAIP that includes the NIR.

I do not believe that Oregon added NIR until the last acquisition of NAIP, but there could be one additional year that includes NIR. For current NAIP (RGB only) for all states, APFO has a webmap service that can be added as a "GIS Server" in ArcGIS (http://gis.apfo.usda.gov/arcgis/services).

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.oregon.gov/DAS/CIO/GEO/pages/data/doq.aspx for some historical imagery.  Google will find it for you and no doubt more by simply searching on Oregon GIS.

The NAIP program only does part of the country in any particular year, and of that only a small amount may be in 4 band or even 1m resolution.  See http://www.fsa.usda.gov/FSA/apfoapp?area=home&subject=prog&topic=nai which has lots of information on the program and even a map showing NAIP coverages from 2003-12.  Bing maps and Google Earth often make use of NAIP imagery and have historical layers.

Comment: John is correct regarding spectral resolution and acquisition cycles. The NAIP program relies on partners, typically state and/or local governments, to fund the NIR band. Since only certain localities may opt for the additional band, the availability of NIR in NAIP imagery is piece-meal. Furthermore, NAIP will acquire part of the country every year, and the other parts of the country the next year. In effect, any given locality is acquired every other year by NAIP.

Comment: @Aaron, I don't quite understand why you think these assertions are incorrect. The acquisition is "targeted" for every other year. The NIR band and designated spatial resolution (currently varying 0.75m-1.0m) is specific to each given state-level contract. The USFS rolled their aerial photography program into APFO and as such, have separate contracts within a given state specifying different acquisition parameters. The spectral ranges can also vary slightly within the R,G,B bands, depending on the contract specs, vendor and sensor used.

Answer (score 1):

From the USDA website/document:
http://www.fsa.usda.gov/Internet/FSA_File/fourband_info_sheet_2013.pdf

> **What states are available in four band?**
>
> In 2007 Arizona was the pilot state for the first four band imagery acquisition through the NAIP
>   program. In 2008, eight states received four band imagery. They were:
>   CT, IN, KS, MN, TN, TX, VT, and VA. In 2009, fifteen states received
>   four band imagery. They were: WA, OR, MT, CA, CO. WY, ID, ND, NE, AL,
>   GA, SC, NC, MD, DE. Starting in 2010, most NAIP imagery contains 4
>   bands. Check [here](http://gis.apfo.usda.gov/gisviewer/default.aspx) for availability. Four band imagery is now a
>   standard product of the NAIP program.

Also, the current "planned" NAIP schedule is every 3 years, however some states have obtained a 2-year revisit based on other federal program needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the historic images, but one can assess the most recent ones from USDA's ArcGIS server: https://gis.apfo.usda.gov/arcgis/rest/services

One can use either ArcGIS Pro or QGIS to export the regions of interest to GeoTIFF or whichever format you prefer.